# Selective string operation

Tags: string, shell, sed, awk, grep

I need help in string processing in CSH/TCSH script.
I know basic processing, but need help understand how we can handle advance string operation requirements.

I have a log file whose format is something like this:

> [START_A]
>
> log info of A
>
> [END_A]
>
> [START_B]
>
> log info of B
>
> [END_B]
>
> [START_C]
>
> log info of C
>
> [END_C]

My requirement is to selectively extract content between start and end tag and store them in a file.
For example the content between START_A and END_A will be stored in A.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk can do them 1 at a time:

```
cat log | awk '/[START_A]/,/[END_A]/'
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I like your answer as it is very simple to understand.

Comment: You can probably make this do all options at once using regex instead of just the static strings.

Comment: This does not work as is, you must backslash the brackets like: `/\[START_A\]/,/\[END_A\]/` see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Bracket-Expressions)

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you:

```
awk -F'_' '/\[START_.\]/{s=1;gsub(/]/,"",$2);f=$2".txt";next;}/\[END_.\]/{s=0} s{print $0 > f}' yourLog
```

**test:**

```
kent$  cat test
    [START_A]

    log info of A

    [END_A]

    [START_B]

    log info of B

    [END_B]

    [START_C]

    log info of C

    [END_C]


kent$  awk -F'_' '/\[START_.\]/{s=1;gsub(/]/,"",$2);f=$2".txt";next;}/\[END_.\]/{s=0} s{print $0 > f}' test

kent$  head *.txt
==> A.txt <==

    log info of A


==> B.txt <==

    log info of B


==> C.txt <==

    log info of C
```

Comment: hey kent, I tried running your example and it ran without giving any error, but failed to generate required files.
This could have been a better solution, since i would be running one line of command instead of multiple commands.
Could you explain a little how the command works. I know basic awk, and would grab the concept with some explanation.
Thanks!!

Comment: This only works for single-character tags and for single line log entries, but it could easily be modified to be more general. +1 in any case.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/.*\[START_\([^]]*\)\].*/s||/\\[START_\1\\]/,/\\[END_\1\\]/w \1.log|p;d' file |
sed -nf - file
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Can you explain a little concept behind your command. I hope to learn what you are trying to do and hopefully see if I am doing anything wrong.
Thanks

Comment: The first part builds a `sed` script which writes the parts of `file` between the start and end delimiters to a log file based on the start delimiter. The second part (after the pipe) reads the generated sed script and runs it agianst the `file`. You can send the first part to a file `> file.sed` and then run it against the file like so : `sed -fn file.sed file`.